# Sharing by criteria to owner of lookup record

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

Suppose we have a custom object `My_Custom__c` that is owned by a queue.
Now that object has a child object `My_Child__c` in a Master-Detail relationship.
Now there is another object `My_Something__c` that has a lookup to `My_Child__c`.

The org will have upwards of 25 **million** rows in `My_Something__c`.
Without writing Apex sharing, is it possible to share `My_Something__c` to the queue where `My_Custom__c` is owned by the same queue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should be handled by the Sharing Setting that you define when creating the Master/Detail field on *My_Child__c*.

[image: Master/Detail Sharing Setting]

As long the following is true, then a queue member should be able to access the *My_Child__c* child records of *My_Custom__c* records within the queue:

1. The user has access to *My_Custom__c* in the user's profile or permission sets
2. The user has access to *My_Child__c* in the user's profile or permission sets
3. The user is a member of the queue

*My_Something__c* record access will be controlled independently of the access to *My_Custom__c* and *My_Child__c*.

Comment: Actually your response made me realise I botched my question renaming all these objects. It is ultimately `My_Something` that I want to control. As `My_Child` is a child in a master-detail then it works out of the box

Comment: If `My_Something` has a Lookup to `My_Child` and it has no other Master/Detail relationship, then you could enable the Queue for the `My_Something` object and you could make sure that Queue members have access to the `My_Something` object in their profiles or permission sets.

Finally, I'm not sure how `My_Something` records get created and by what user, but you could consider a flow to reassign new `My_Something` records to the Queue.

Comment: so this is great if `My_Something` is owned by the same queue or is public as far as OWD goes. But the idea here is that I want the recrods to NOT change ownership yet be visible to anyone who can access my `My_Custom__c` object.